# Retrieve data conditionally with Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire

My Firebase database contains objects with the following format:

```
"documentation": {
   "scotch": {
     "URL": "https://scotch.io",
     "description": "Fun and practical web development",
     "level": 0,
     "name": "Scotch",
     "tech": ["angular", "angularjs", "react", "laravel", "java"],
     "type": "web"
   },
   ...
}
```

I wish to retrieve a list of said objects by using the `tech` attribute.
For example, I want to query every `documentation` that contains the tech `angular`; can that be achieved?

So far the only way I filter my documentation is by querying all of it like such:

```
dbRef = this.firebase.database().ref().child('documentation');

this.dbRef.on('value', snap => {
   documentation = snap.val();
}
```

And filtering it client-side, which would be unnecessary if my question gets answered.

Thank you !

**UPDATE**:

I'm able to query by `type`, `level`, `description` (every key that has one value), but can't seem to query by `tech` as it is an array of strings.

Here is how I do it:

```
// Returns Stackoverflow as it is the only documentation that has the type Q&A
let ref = this.firebase.database().ref().child('documentation').orderByChild('type').equalTo('Q&A').on('value', snap => {
  doc = snap.val();
  console.log(doc);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create an index of "tech" to query from. This will require to maintain an extra data structure, but the querying will be simple.

```
{
  "documentation": {
     "scotch": {
       "URL": "https://scotch.io",
       "description": "Fun and practical web development",
       "level": 0,
       "name": "Scotch",
       "tech": ["angular", "angularjs", "react", "laravel", "java"],
       "type": "web"
     }  
  },
  "tech": {
    "angular": {
       "scotch": {
         ... demnormalized value
       }
    },
    "angularjs": {
       "scotch": {
         ... demnormalized value
       }
    },
    "react": {
       "scotch": {
         ... demnormalized value
       }
    }
  }
}
```

This way you can easily query like so:

```
const createTechRef = (tech) => {
  return firebase.database().ref('tech').child(tech);
};

const angularRef = createTechRef('angular');
angularRef.on('value', snap => {
  // all angular "techs"
});
```